# LINQ-to-XML in HtmlAgilityPack to select TR

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml, html-agility-pack

This may straightforward for someone, so if you are that one please take a look at this:

I have a table with more rows, but one row I want to extract based on a given text, here is the table excerpt:

```
 ... <tr>
    <td class="border-1px-solid-black" colspan="1">
      <img onclick="PopupCenter('{{InvoiceDetails.0.Link}}')" style="max-height: 35px; max-width: 35px; cursor: pointer;" src="/images/report.png" /></td>
    <td class="border-1px-solid-black" colspan="11">
      <p>{{InvoiceDetails.0.Description}}</p>
    </td>
    <td class="border-1px-solid-black" colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">
      <p>{{InvoiceDetails.0.Quantity}}</p>
    </td>
    <td class="border-1px-solid-black" colspan="2" style="text-align: right;">
      <p>{{InvoiceDetails.0.Amount}}  </p>
    </td>
  </tr>...
```

I am using HtmlAgilityPack and VB.NET and I want to get TR that contains InvoiceDetails.0 in any element.

How to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will post the way I've finished this, but this is not the shortest way:

```
          nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[text()[contains(., '" + find + "')]]")
          If nodes IsNot Nothing Then
            node = nodes(0)
            While node.ParentNode.Name <> "tr"
              node = node.ParentNode
            End While
            node = node.ParentNode
            'and here I have reference to TR node
            Next
          End If
```

If you have shorter way please write here.